# how to pass form data to controller when 'document.formname.submit()' is used to submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying submit an html form with a link(inplace of form button) using javascript.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
echo form_open('controller/method', 'id=formid', 'name=formname');
echo form_hidden('uniqval', 'somevalue');  //here some value is the actual string that
                                   //needs to be passed to the controller's function                              
?>
<a href="link/controller/method" onclick="handler();">Submit</a> 
<?php echo form_close();  ?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function handler(){       
      //document.formname.uniqval.value = 'somevalue'; //not sure if this is required 
      document.formname.submit();
    }
</script>
```

My question how do I pass the hidden form data to the controller in php codeigniter.
I am trying to read it through regular post method,

using $this->input->post('uniqval');

when I give the actual url path for href in  it is calling the funcion, but the value is not being passed.

Any ideas or examples will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should form_close() is one thing; then change "controller/method" to be the actual controller & method names

since your anchor tag is not really an anchor, href="#"

Comment: Thank you. I have a form_close() in my code. and about controller/method, I have actual controller function in the form_open() and for href, I gave the complete link like href="www.example.com/controller/function", its not working with href="#". Anyway, it is calling the right function. but the only problem is the hidden form data is not being passed to the controller method.

Comment: then you should update this question with the ACTUAL code you are using; it is very difficult to debug a psuedo-code version

Answer (score 0):

There were some problems with your code (in php, html and JS).

**PHP:**

- you must need to close the form with **`form_close()`**.
- **`form_close()`** accepts attributes as an array format, this is why the form name was missing and the javascript couldn't find a form to submit.

  ```
  <?php
      echo form_open('controller/method', array('id'=>'formid', 'name'=>'formname'));
      echo form_hidden('hidden', 'somevalue');  
      echo form_close();    
  ?>
  ```

***FYI: `form_hidden()` doesn't accept attributes in the parameters. This irrelevant here.***

**HTML:**

- You must make the **`<a>`** unclickable.

  ```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="handler();">Submit</a>
  ```

**`Javascript:`**

- No need to pass the hidden value through javascript. So, I removed that line.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function handler()
      {      
          document.formname.submit();
      }
  </script>
  ```

Now the form submit will work and you can use **`$this->input->post("somevalue")`** to capture the value.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you IJas. I tried this, but it is not working. I think I am close though. with href="javascript:void(0)", it is just going to a blank page, its not calling the right method, unless I give the complete url for href. I have updated my code in the post. Can you please take another look.

Comment: Check this line **`echo form_open('controller/method', 'id=formid', 'name=formname');`**, this is wrong. Check my line. It should be like **`echo form_open('controller/method', array('id'=>'formid', 'name'=>'formname'));`**

Comment: You should pass the form attributes in an array. Without it, javascript will not find a form to submit. I have already mentioned this in my answer. Also keep the **`href`** as mine. otherwise it will  redirect you to the url you give, will not submit the form. Hope I made you clear.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. But, when I do this <a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/method" onclick="handler();">Submit</a>, it should open the page a fancy box popup, thats the reason why I am using a link to submit instead of form_submit(), It opened in a fancybox before I corrected the error, you pointed out. Any idea on that??

Comment: If you are using along with another plugin, then keep the link. The plugin should stop the redirect in default.

Comment: so you are saying, I should keep the link for href in <a>. What is happening is, if the function is called with href link its opening in a fancybox, but the hidden field value is not being passed to the function. If I correct the form_open() and call the function thru action of form_open(), the hidden value is being passed to the function, but not opening as a fancy box popup. Is there is any work around for this??

Comment: I think you should post this problem as a separate question man. I already answered your original question. FYI, fancybox has inbuilt AJAX feature and through that you can pass this variable.

Comment: Welcome, post as another question. I'll try answer there.